# Error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-c++-2015

I have a virtual function inside a C++ templated task, and when it is compiled in Visual Studio 2015 (I have tried all combinations of Debug/Release and x86/x64), it consistently fails with compiler error C1001 on the following line of code:

```
e_Ty *d(new e_Ty[l]);
```

Where `e_Ty` is the template parameter of the class. This error only occurs when I use the template class with `e_Ty` set to `std::pair<const int &, int &>`. Is there a legitimate reason why this should not work, or is this a bug in MSVC?

---

**EDIT**

Notes:

- `l` is a local variable that was declared (and assigned a value as a result of a function call) ahead of time.
- I have tried using disabling optimization, using `auto`, and using assignment-style initialization, none of which worked.
- Code compiles fine when `e_Ty` is `int`.

Comment: This is ill-formed code anyway. How exactly do you create a pair of references without binding them to anything?

Comment: @T.C.: Thanks, the type didn't register with me. Fixed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @T.C. Thank you, I changed it to use `std::pair<int, int>` and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An internal compiler error, an **ICE**, is *always* a bug.

Please report it via Microsoft Connect.

---

The code in question,

```
e_Ty *d(new e_Ty[l]);
```

… <del>may or may not be correct depending on `l`, whether appropriate headers have been included, and so on. There's too little context to say.</del> is invalid for `e_Ty` as a `std::pair` of references, because references need to be initialized, as [noted by T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602558/error-c1001-an-internal-error-has-occurred-in-the-compiler/37602598?noredirect=1#comment62691052_37602558). But that doesn't matter for an ICE.

Comment: Thank you, I'll submit it to Microsoft. Also, I edited my question to clarify that `l` is a local variable, and that it works with `int`.

Comment: _An internal compiler error, an ICE, is always a bug._ Someone would call it _a feature_ anyway. :-)

Comment: See [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/974229) for details on making a good repro

Answer (score 0):

It's worth seeing if it's related to:
[C++11 constexpr causes compiler's internal error (C1001)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696112/c11-constexpr-causes-compilers-internal-error-c1001/50811995#50811995)

If there is a constexpr involved, VS2015 and VS2017 compilers have been reported to crash when used with template code.